# CSV data scraping with python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I am working on a project based on a dataset (https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/blob/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv).
I am only interested in three columns, 'continent', 'date', and a data column. I want to add all data from the same continents and dates, such as to have a progression of each continents data by date.

this is my current code (so far I've created dictionaries and a recursion to fill them with each date-entry data):

```
df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\julio\Desktop\proyect\owid-covid-data.csv')
print(df.iloc[0,1])# continent
print(df.iloc[0,3])# date
print(df.iloc[0,5])# data (new_cases)
Africa=dict()
Europe=dict()
Asia=dict()
NorthAmerica=dict()
SouthAmerica=dict()
Oceania=dict()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['continent']=='Asia':
        Asia.update({df.iloc[index,3],df.iloc[index,5]})
    if row['continent']=='Africa':
        Africa.update({df.iloc[index,3],df.iloc[index,5]})
    if row['continent']=='Europe':
        Europe.update({df.iloc[index,3],df.iloc[index,5]})
    if row['continent']=='North America':
        NorthAmerica.update({df.iloc[index,3],df.iloc[index,5]})
    if row['continent']=='South America':
        SouthAmerica.update({df.iloc[index,3],df.iloc[index,5]})
    if row['continent']=='Oceania':
        Oceania.update({df.iloc[index,3],df.iloc[index,5]})
```

I get an error saying that there are more than the 2 items needed for the dictionary update.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First, add the data for each continent and date.

`df.groupby(['continent', 'date'])['data'].sum().reset_index()`

Then, sort the data by continent and date in the ascending order

`df.sort_values(['continent', 'date'], ascending=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Rajesh C's answer works well to generate the data set you want.

Specific to the error message, if I understand what you are trying to do correctly, it's

```
Asia.update({df.iloc[index,3]:df.iloc[index,5]})
```

similar for other continents.

Here are some examples I found to help you understand the syntax of `dict.update` https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/update

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand the logic behind creating dictionaries and the iterrows loop.  But here is a way to download the three columns in the original post.

```
import pandas as pd
filename = ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com'
            '/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv')
fields = ['continent', 'date', 'new_cases']
df_raw = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=fields, parse_dates=['date'])
```

Now, re-shape to transform dates to row labels and continents to column labels:

```
df = df_raw.pivot_table(index='date',
                        columns='continent',
                        values='new_cases',
                        aggfunc='sum',
                        fill_value=0,
                       )
print(df.tail())

continent   Africa   Asia  Europe  North America  Oceania  South America
date                                                                    
2020-08-11    8828  81397   23272          60213      331          46289
2020-08-12    7895  88186   19821          59165      402          85542
2020-08-13    9529  94335   26994          67675      493          89787
2020-08-14   10515  92004   25367          64727      285          93364
2020-08-15   12689  95916   18686          76850      434          84099
```